# Azure Storage Authentication failing - Audience validation failed. Audience did not match. [AZURE][OAuth]

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

I am trying to make a REST call to Azure Storage using the following code.
[image]

But It shows following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
   <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\n' +
        'RequestId:11c07be7-301e-0003-556f-42091d000000\n' +
        'Time:2021-05-06T11:59:40.1049759Z</Message>
   <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Audience validation failed. Audience did not match.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

I have already assigned roles:
[image]

And have API permissions set:
[image]

But still this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you getting access token? Please edit your question and include that. Also please paste code and not a screenshot of it.

Comment: If you inspect the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms, you can check what the "aud" claim contains. It should be the Azure Storage ID URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The audience of your access token is not correct. The `aud`(audience) should look like `https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net`.

Make sure the `scope` is `https://{account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation` when requesting for access token.

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Mayank Patel. Is there any update? Does it help?

Comment: Please provide us with this postman collection. Of course omit any sensitive information but, I need this thing I'm busy running around in circle. This would be very helpful.